# The Java Media Framework isn't cross platform?

Tags: java, user-interface, cross-platform, jmf

I'm using JMF in my Java GUI and before downloading the packages from Oracle, it asks you which version you want:

```
Linux 
Solaris SPARC 
Windows
```

Does this mean my Java (cross-platform by nature) application WON'T be cross platform any more?

Comment: this is unikely to change since the API has not been enhanced since 1999, and the last news item on JMF's home page was posted in September 2008...

Comment: I just need it to work in a windows and linux environment. I'm trying to figure out if my code needs to be modified to deal with windows or if someone using my application in windows just needs to install something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a 100% pure Java implementation, but that does not support all codecs and doesn't run as efficiently as the version using native code. So, effectively, the JMF is not fully cross-platform.

The developers justify this by considering the JMF an extension to the Java platform itself rather than just a library: just like you have to download a specific JVM for your platform, but can reuse your source and object code unchanged, you need a platform-dependent JMF implementation, but the JMF clients can be reused unchanged.

Comment: The JMF version with natives is called the Performance Pack.  AFAIU whatever it is that JMF does with natives is not supported in any way in the cross-platform version, so it is hard to see how there could be any difference in speed.  One thing that definitely requires the PP is web-cams.  The OP might get a further idea of the differences between them, from the [JMF - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) page.

Comment: Yeah I found the pure Java version and I think I'll go for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMF isn't a pure Java API, so it'll only work where it's officially ported.

Comment: So is there a way for me to get it to work in both a Linux and Windows environment? Would my code change or would the operating system just need different things installed?

Comment: @MaxMackie, have you tried comparing the linux and windows packages to see what the differences are ? If it's like JOGL (openGL port to Java), then you might only need to point to different librairies at runtime, in which case you would only need a different launch script for the various platform... only guessing here though

Comment: -1 There is an x-plat (i.e. pure Java) version.  See Kilian Foth's answer.